# Combinatorial Argument with Natural Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, combinatorial-proofs

Give a combinatorial argument to show that all natural numbers n ≥ k ≥ m

c(n,k) * c(k,m) = c(n,m) * c((n-m),(k-m)) where c stands for combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $n$ different doughnuts, and want to choose $k$ of them to eat today, of which $m$ are to be eaten this morning. We count the number of ways to do it.  Here are two ways to do the counting.

**Way 1:** We choose the $k$ doughnuts for today, then choose the ones for this morning from the $k$ selected. The $k$ doughnuts for today can be chosen in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways, and for each of these the ones for this morning can be chosen in $\binom{k}{m}$ ways.

**Way 2:** We choose the ones for this morning. This can be done in $\binom{n}{m}$ ways. Then we choose the ones for the rest of the day, $\binom{n-m}{k-m}$ ways.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing $m\leq k\leq n$, these are two different expressions for the trinomial coefficient $\binom n{m,k-m,n-k}$, the number of ways to colour $n$ points so $m$ are red, $k-m$ are white, and the remaining $n-k$ are blue. (1) Select the blue points, then among the remaining points the red points, respectively (2) select the red points, then among the remaining points the white points.

Answer (score 1):

since we know c(n,k)=n!/(n-k)!k!

L.H.S= c(n,k) * c(k,m)
     = (n!/(n-k)!k!)*(k!/(k-m)!m!)
     =n!/(n-k)!(k-m)!m!=trinomial coefficient (n m,k−m,n−k)

R.H.S=c(n,m) * c((n-m),(k-m))
     =(n!/(n-m)!m!)*((n-m)!/(n-k)!(k-m)!)
     =n!/(n-k)!(k-m)!m!=trinomial coefficient (n m,k−m,n−k)

so c(n,k) * c(k,m) = c(n,m) * c((n-m),(k-m))=trinomial coefficient (n m,k−m,n−k)